# How to write correct file path with an environment variable in python?

Tags: python, path

I would like to write the file path with an windows environment variable for the windows username but I don't know how to write it correctly. I would like to use an env variable because I use the script on different computers.

Here is the code:

```
import os

os_username = os.environ.get('USERNAME')

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r"C:\Users\" + os_username + r"\Google-Drive\filename.xlsx")
```

The above code does not work to find the correct path.
The code for finding the username is working.
The file path would be for instance: C:\Users\Peter\Google-Drive\filename.xlsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create string for your path. And you can use '/' or 'double backslash' instead

Try this:

```
my_path = fr"C:/Users/{os_username}/Google-Drive/filename.xlsx"
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(my_path)
```

[see here for windows path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953843/9545326)